# Brave Browser sessionStorage error. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, session-storage, brave

Brave browser is returning this message:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

The related code is:

`sessionStorage.setItem("status", 0);`

Why is that? How do I solve the problem? In other browser (Safari, Chrome) the `sessionStorage` works fine.

Comment: Why? It's in the error -> _"Access denied for this document"_.

Comment: Brave is so internet safe, that  even `sessionStorage` can't be accessed ...

Comment: See this, it might help: [How do I allow my local web page access to LocalStorage in Brave Browser?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55620680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the storage from a frame or an iframe with different origins.

For security reasons, Brave blocks those requests.

You can [configure your shields](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022806212-How-do-I-use-Shields-while-browsing) and allow cross site cookies.